# How i can make 2 admins for one entity in Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

How i can make 2 admins for one entity in Sonata Admin?
For example - one admin shows a list with `"status=1"` condition, and other with `"status=2".`

it would be great if make a new record in first admin automatically sets the `"status=1".`

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) create a one admin class in ADMIN Directory with Your condition `status=1`

2) create a second admin class in ADMIN Directory with Your condition `status=2`

3) config that class in sonata_admin.yaml with different name

4) change in second admin `$baseRouteName` and `$baseRoutePattern` to different

In which Entity name is same

Comment: It does't work. It takes the last admin with same entity. Both have one url.

Comment: Second admin class in change route
And also change route pattern